# Typescript: Place constraint on specific lookup type of generic object type

Tags: typescript, generics, functional-programming, constraints, mapped-types

Alright so here's the problem. I have the following type and function definitions:

```
export type compareFunction<T> = (t1: T, t2: T) => boolean

function createCompareFunctionCreator<P>(customCompare: compareFunction<P>) {
    return <
        T,
        K extends keyof T
    >(propName: K) => {
        return (t1: T, t2: T) => customCompare(t1[propName], t2[propName]) as compareFunction<P>
    }
}
```

My question is, how would place a particular constraint such that `T[propName]` is of type `P`?

I've tried the following:

```
function createCompareFunctionCreator<P>(customCompare: compareFunction<P>) {
    return <
        T extends { [keys in keyof T]: P },
        K extends keyof T
    >(propName: K) => {
        return (t1: T, t2: T) => customCompare(t1[propName], t2[propName]) as compareFunction<P>
    }
}
```

But this forces ALL properties in `T` to map to type `P`.

Comment: `T extends {[keys in K]: P}` aka `T extends Record<K, P>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Force T to have all properties of T

The problem is lack of relation between `P` and `T`. We can solve that but setting the relation. Consider following code:

```
export type compareFunction<T> = (t1: T, t2: T) => boolean

function createCompareFunctionCreator<P>(customCompare: compareFunction<P>) {
    return <
        T extends Record<K, P>, // pay attention here
        K extends keyof T
    >(propName: K) => {
        return (t1: T, t2: T) => customCompare(t1[propName], t2[propName])
    }
}
```

`T extends Record<K, P>` is saying that our type `T` is an object which all properties are type of `P`. Thanks to that we can do `t1[propName]` and we know that its type of `P`.

## Force T to have properties of P with other properties

We can achieve that by some additional typing consider:

```
// utility type which gives us only keys which values in T1 are T2
type OnlyKeysOfT<T1, T2> = {
    [K in keyof T1]: T1[K] extends T2 ? K : never
}[keyof T1]

function createCompareFunctionCreator<P>(customCompare: compareFunction<P>) {
    return <
        T extends Record<K, P>,
        K extends OnlyKeysOfT<T, P> = OnlyKeysOfT<T, P>,
    >(propName: K) => {
        return (t1: T, t2: T) => customCompare(t1[propName], t2[propName])
    }
}
// below only a is correct
createCompareFunctionCreator<string>((a,b) => true)<{a: string, b: number}>('a')
```

Comment: Ah! yes, your solution in the bottom section is exactly what I'm looking for. If I called with 'b' instead of 'a' in your example, the TS error message would say ` Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"' `, which isn't quite as helpful as I would hope, but it still works. Ideally, the error message would tell me something about the fact that 'b' doesn't map to a string, but that's an after-thought. The error message at least gives me what properties I can choose from.

Comment: Yes I have seen that TS not helps in message here, but what is allowed/not is correct.